# Create a new array of object by pushing elements in the array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object which looks like:

```
const orderp = [{id: "1", items:[{id:"1", Name: "Peter"}, {id:"2", Name: "John"}]}, {id: "2", items:[{id:"1", Name: "Teresa"}, {id:"2", Name: "stephan"}]}, {id: "3", items:[{id:"1", Name: "stuart"}, {id:"2", Name: "Jeny"}]}]
```

Now, For this I am trying to create an combine an array which will have only `items` object values only.

Desired output would be :

```
const names = [{id:"1", Name: "Peter"}, {id:"2", Name: "John"},{id:"1", Name: "Teresa"}, {id:"2", Name: "stephan"}, {id:"1", Name: "stuart"}, {id:"2", Name: "Jeny"}]
```

For this I tried:

```
let names = []
for (order of orderp) {
  for(name of order['items']) {
    names.push(name)
}
```

}

One more thing thing that would be using iterator of number:

```
for(let i =0; i <= orderp.length-1; i ++){

}
```

like this.

But is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The first snippet should work. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce and inside callback use concat to concat the items array with accumulator array

```js
let data = [{
  id: "1",
  items: [{
    id: "1",
    Name: "Peter"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    Name: "John"
  }]
}, {
  id: "2",
  items: [{
    id: "1",
    Name: "Teresa"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    Name: "stephan"
  }]
}, {
  id: "3",
  items: [{
    id: "1",
    Name: "stuart"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    Name: "Jeny"
  }]
}];


const newData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 return acc.concat(curr.items)
}, []);
console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for this purpose, see from the documentation:

> The `flatMap()` method returns a new array formed by applying a given callback function to each element of the array, and then flattening the result by one level. It is identical to a `map()` followed by a `flat()` of depth 1, but slightly more efficient than calling those two methods separately.

Try as the following:

```js
const orderp = [{id: "1", items:[{id:"1", Name: "Peter"}, {id:"2", Name: "John"}]}, {id: "2", items:[{id:"1", Name: "Teresa"}, {id:"2", Name: "stephan"}]}, {id: "3", items:[{id:"1", Name: "stuart"}, {id:"2", Name: "Jeny"}]}]
const names = orderp.flatMap(e => e.items)
console.log(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done through array map function as well

```js
const orderp = [
    { id: '1', items: [ { id: '1', Name: 'Peter' }, { id: '2', Name: 'John' }]},{ id: '2', items: [ { id: '1', Name: 'Teresa' }, { id: '2', Name: 'stephan' } ] },{ id: '3', items: [ { id: '1', Name: 'stuart' }, { id: '2', Name: 'Jeny' } ] }];
        let arr = [];
        orderp.map((item) => {
            if (item['items']) {
                if (Object.entries(item['items'].length > 1)) {
                    Object.entries(item['items']).map((item) => {
                        arr.push(item[1]);
                    });
                } else {
                    arr.push(item[1]);
                }
            }
        });
        console.log(arr);
```